# PrestaShop Server Error (DEV SITE): This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset

Tags: php, prestashop, vps, prestashop-1.7, http-status-code-503

I'm currently facing an issue that has been bothering me for the past few days. Here's the situation:

I've set up a '/dev/' folder to make changes to my PrestaShop website. I've recently updated PS to version 1.7.8.10 (the main website is still on 1.7.7.4) and commenced working on website edits. However, I've encountered a problem where certain media elements fail to load correctly. Additionally, whenever I attempt to access the back office (and subsequently the main website), Chrome displays the following error message on my IP only:

"This site can’t be reached

The connection was reset.

Try:

Checking the connection

Checking the proxy and the firewall

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Furthermore, I'm using Elementor for website editing, and I'm experiencing issues there as well. Occasionally, I can't access the photo library, and sometimes I encounter a 503 error when trying to access the visual editor. Strangely, these problems seem to come and go intermittently. When I do encounter these errors, I typically wait around 10 minutes, and then everything starts working again, only to fail once more after about 2 minutes, followed by the same error message.

I reached out to the server host and they told me that everything seems to be working fine on their end. I am using a VPS.

I'm quite perplexed and struggling to pinpoint the source of this error. If anyone has any insights or suggestions that could help me resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of things you have to do after making a copy of your website:

- make sure you have correct URLs and virtual/physical URI set up in the `PREFIX_shop_url` table
- make sure to remove /var/cache/ directory and its content
- make sure to delete the .htaccess file from the main directory and regenerate it from back office
- make sure to use incognito mode, as having the same shop on the same server, in the directory and not on the subdomain, might cause issues with the cookies

Also, if you have Error 503, it doesn't say anything. You must enable the developer mode, e.g., by editing the `/config/defines.inc.php` and changing `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to `true`. It should show you a more informative error.

Comment: I tried all of this and unfortunately it does not work. I am afraid that it is a misconfiguration with the firewall or something, but my server host tells me that everything is fine on their end.. 
I also cannot access PHPadmin as the same error message appears. I feel like my IP is temporarily banned or something.

Comment: Ok, if you have the same error with phpMyAdmin, then maybe there is some server misconfiguration.